# Eureka - If peer goes down, instances spam a lot of logs

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

we have an eureka setup with two peers.
These two peers are running on two different virtual machines, testvm01.mydomain.com and testvm02.mydomain.com.

These two peers use the following configurations.

Peer1:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: testvm01.mydomain.com
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://testvm02.mydomain.com:8761/eureka
  dashboard:
    enabled: true
```

Peer2:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: testvm02.mydomain.com
    leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://testvm01.mydomain.com:8761/eureka
  server:
    waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
  dashboard:
    enabled: true
```

If i shutdown own of these two eureka peers now, the other one produces a lot of log messages like the following one:

```
2015-05-28 12:07:18.675 ERROR 15871 --- [artbeat-process] c.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode  : PeerEurekaNode: http://testvm01.mydomain.com:8761/eurekaapps/: MAIL-SERVICE/testvm02.mydomain.com:mail-service:9880:Heartbeat

com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:184)
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:28)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:648)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:680)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.put(WebResource.java:527)
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode.sendHeartBeat(PeerEurekaNode.java:510)
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode.access$400(PeerEurekaNode.java:72)
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode$3.execute(PeerEurekaNode.java:275)
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode$6.executeSingle(PeerEurekaNode.java:992)
    at com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode$6.process(PeerEurekaNode.java:844)
    at com.netflix.logging.messaging.MessageBatcher$ProcessMessages.run(MessageBatcher.java:410)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.SocketInputBuffer.fillBuffer(SocketInputBuffer.java:84)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.readLine(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:273)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:57)
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:260)
    at org.apache.http.impl.AbstractHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractHttpClientConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultClientConnection.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractClientConnAdapter.receiveResponseHeader(AbstractClientConnAdapter.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:271)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryExecute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:685)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:487)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:115)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:170)
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

These produces around 5 GB of log messages in less than 3 hours.

Is something wrong with my configuration? Is this a bug either in spring-cloud or in eureka?
What can i do to handle this properly? For now i just turned off logging for com.netflix.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNode, but this is for sure unacceptable for a production environment later on.

Versions:
Spring-Boot: 1.2.3.RELEASE
Spring-Cloud-Starter-Parent-Bom: 1.0.1.RELEASE

Comment: In practice `leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds: 3` is probably not good for production either.  Netflix uses 30 seconds.

Comment: The eureka server tries to replicate every changes it is notified to its peer. This could be a heartbeat received from a client or a new registration. This process is handled by the `PeerEurekaNode`. When it fails to contact its peer, it logs an exception and retries _immediately_ (waits a couple of ms, but not much). It keeps trying until the replication message expires (a couple of seconds). So you end up with a huge amount of stack traces in a couple of seconds... And it starts again for the next received heartbeat... The more clients you have, the worst it becomes.

Comment: @BertrandRenuart Yes, i thought already that it would be something like this. But is there any chance to tell eureka "try it twice and then drop this"?
So at some point, the server should simply recognize, that the peer isn't there at the moment and stop trying to replicate. Possibly mark the peer as "down" and try to connect to him every minute or so and set him back "up" if the peer is available again....

Comment: @spencergibb yes. you are right and this was only to test out what is a good setting at this point. We are still playing around with the whole spring-cloud stuff because it is our first cloud project.

Comment: @Koizumi Not as far as I know... I looked at the problem for a couple of days and couldn't find a solution. Maybe someone with "better Netflix's internals" knowledge could answer.